# Add "add to compare" and "add to Wishlist" functionality in minicart magento 2

Tags: magento2

i want to Add "add to compare" and "add to Wishlist" functionality in minicart magento 2.

I cannot find where to modify. Can you help me, please?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

I have implemented Add To Wishlist functionality in the minicart.

There are two things to do.

1. Override Magento_Checkout mini-cart template in your theme. i.e.

Take `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/item/default.html` into `app/design/frontend/Custom/theme/Magento_Checkout/web/template/minicart/item/default.html`

Add `Add To Wishlist` anchor tag near Remove Item anchor tag. Like,

```
<div class="product actions">
     <div class="secondary">
          <!-- ko if: is_visible_in_site_visibility -->
          <a data-bind="attr: {'data-post': wishlist_data, title: $t('Add to wishlist')}" class="action wishlist">
               <span data-bind="i18n: 'Add to wishlist'"></span>
          </a>
          <!-- /ko -->
          <a href="#" data-bind="attr: {'data-cart-item': item_id, title: $t('Remove item')}" class="action delete">
               <span data-bind="i18n: 'Remove'"></span>
          </a>
     </div>
</div>
```

2. Override Magento_Checkout CustomerData DefaultItem.php file.

Add below in Custom module's di.xml

```
<preference for="Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\DefaultItem"
type="Custom\Module\CustomerData\Preference\DefaultItem"/>
```

Added below code in preference overrided file.

```
<?php
namespace Custom\Module\CustomerData\Preference;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Configuration\Item\ItemResolverInterface;

class DefaultItem extends \Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\DefaultItem
{
/**
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image
 */
protected $imageHelper;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Msrp\Helper\Data
 */
protected $msrpHelper;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface
 */
protected $urlBuilder;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\ConfigurationPool
 */
protected $configurationPool;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Checkout\Helper\Data
 */
protected $checkoutHelper;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Escaper
 */
private $escaper;

/**
 * @var ItemResolverInterface
 */
private $itemResolver;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data
 */
private $wishlistHelper;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image $imageHelper
 * @param \Magento\Msrp\Helper\Data $msrpHelper
 * @param \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlBuilder
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\ConfigurationPool $configurationPool
 * @param \Magento\Checkout\Helper\Data $checkoutHelper
 * @param \Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data $wishlistHelper
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Escaper|null $escaper
 * @param ItemResolverInterface|null $itemResolver
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image $imageHelper,
    \Magento\Msrp\Helper\Data $msrpHelper,
    \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlBuilder,
    \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\ConfigurationPool $configurationPool,
    \Magento\Checkout\Helper\Data $checkoutHelper,
    \Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data $wishlistHelper,
    \Magento\Framework\Escaper $escaper = null,
    ItemResolverInterface $itemResolver = null
) {
    $this->wishlistHelper = $wishlistHelper;
    $this->escaper = $escaper ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(\Magento\Framework\Escaper::class);
    $this->itemResolver = $itemResolver ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(ItemResolverInterface::class);
    parent::__construct($imageHelper, $msrpHelper, $urlBuilder, $configurationPool, $checkoutHelper);
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
protected function doGetItemData()
{
    $imageHelper = $this->imageHelper->init($this->getProductForThumbnail(), 'mini_cart_product_thumbnail');
    $productName = $this->escaper->escapeHtml($this->item->getProduct()->getName());

    return [
        'options' => $this->getOptionList(),
        'qty' => $this->item->getQty() * 1,
        'item_id' => $this->item->getId(),
        'configure_url' => $this->getConfigureUrl(),
        'wishlist_data' => $this->getAddToWishlistParams(),
        'is_visible_in_site_visibility' => $this->item->getProduct()->isVisibleInSiteVisibility(),
        'product_id' => $this->item->getProduct()->getId(),
        'product_name' => $productName,
        'product_sku' => $this->item->getProduct()->getSku(),
        'product_url' => $this->getProductUrl(),
        'product_has_url' => $this->hasProductUrl(),
        'product_price' => $this->checkoutHelper->formatPrice($this->item->getCalculationPrice()),
        'product_price_value' => $this->item->getCalculationPrice(),
        'product_image' => [
            'src' => $imageHelper->getUrl(),
            'alt' => $imageHelper->getLabel(),
            'width' => $imageHelper->getWidth(),
            'height' => $imageHelper->getHeight(),
        ],
        'canApplyMsrp' => $this->msrpHelper->isShowBeforeOrderConfirm($this->item->getProduct())
            && $this->msrpHelper->isMinimalPriceLessMsrp($this->item->getProduct()),
    ];
}

protected function getAddToWishlistParams()
{
    $params = ['qty' => $this->item->getQty()];
    return $this->wishlistHelper->getAddParams($this->item->getProduct(), $params);
}
}
```

This will add a link in Mini-cart near Remove Item and Clicking on it will add cart item into wishlist.

Comment: i tried same way, here it won't add the configurable options on wish list. how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Hope you doing well.

please find this file here.

**magento-directory/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/item/default.html**

please override this template file and your Wishlist and Compare Functionality as Edit and delete functionality work here.

**this is Block file from where magento set url and all data.**

> **magento-directory/vendor/magento/module-checkout/Block/Cart/Sidebar.php**

Please find related files here:

> **magento-directory/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/content.html**
>
> **magento-directory/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/minicart.js**
>
> **magento-directory/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/sidebar.js**

please properly check and do as Delete Functionality works in minicart.
so you can easily achieve what you want.

> **magento-directory/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/item/default.html**

```
<a href="#" data-bind="attr: {'data-cart-item': item_id, title: $t('Remove item')}"
                       class="action delete">
                        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Remove'"></span>
                    </a>
```

**magento-directory/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/minicart.js**

```
'url': {
         'remove': window.checkout.removeItemUrl,
       },
'button':{
         'remove': '#mini-cart a.action.delete',
        },
```

**magento-directory/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/sidebar.js**

```
events['click ' + this.options.button.remove] =  function (event) {
                event.stopPropagation();
                confirm({
                    content: self.options.confirmMessage,
                    actions: {
                        /** @inheritdoc */
                        confirm: function () {
                            self._removeItem($(event.currentTarget));
                        },

                        /** @inheritdoc */
                        always: function (e) {
                            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                        }
                    }
                });
            };

_removeItem: function (elem) {
            var itemId = elem.data('cart-item');

            this._ajax(this.options.url.remove, {
                'item_id': itemId
            }, elem, this._removeItemAfter);
        },
```

Thanks